# Embedding jquery code in WP head

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to run my jquery code on WP.

I use the correct hook (`wp_head`/`admin_head`) and dump the `script tag` in the `head tag` of the page after the the theme has linked jquery but it causes the following error and my script doesn't run.

**Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery is not defined**

Comment: Can you double confirm your jQuery codes are written AFTER jQuery is included in the page ?

Comment: Read here on how to add scripts the WordPress way: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: @ShivanRaptor yes, it is also successfully linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I maybe way out of focus here - and you did not show your whole code ( which is usefull in these cases ) , but ...

from the error message :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: **jquery** is not defined

maybe you need to write `jQuery` not `jquery` ( capital `Q` - javascript is case sensitive ) ...

That is ment for the script itself, not the dependencies of `wp_enqueue_script()` which do reference `jQuery` as `jquery` ...

Comment: You were actually pretty focused, thanks.

But I don't know why $ alias doesn't work. Console says its not a function.

Comment: When Using WordPress try always to avoid the `$` Alias when possible. Wordpress loads jQuery in [No conflict Mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). I always just change all of those aliases to `jQuery` in order to avoid errors.  [More Details](http://www.mojowill.com/developer/using-javascript-with-wordpress-correctly/) ( read at bottom )

Answer (score 1):

Look at the document for [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).  If you look at the $deps parameter, you can use this in order to make sure that jquery gets loaded before your other jQuery calls in other js files.